# How to log out and back in using a bash script

Tags: login, ulimit

I am trying to set [`ulimit`](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) when starting an EC2 instance on Amazon Web Services.

Is there any way to write a script that will:

1. `sudo` root to set `ulimit`, then:
2. Log out and back in as my original user in order to run some commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Increase ulimit in /etc/security/limits.conf](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit/) or by executing `sudo ulimit -n number_of_files`
2. Open a new login shell by typing either `ssh localhost` or `su - username`

Comment: It works interactively, but when I put the following into a script, it does not work well. Here is my script: `sudo bash

ulimit -n 1000000
su - hadoop`

Comment: Can you provide more clarity about exactly what you're trying to do?  Are you testing different values of `ulimit`? Do you just want `ulimit` to be set to a given value every time you log in?

Comment: I am starting a new EC2 instance every time I run the script. So that I am not able to set `ulimit` manually. I do want `ulimit` to be set to a given value every time I log in.

Comment: Ah, so really what you want to be able to do, I think, is to customize limits.conf (http://ss64.com/bash/limits.conf.html) for each new instance you spin up.  That's an AWS question, and I have no experience there.  You may want to edit your question to be more general, to clarify this.

Comment: Googling a bit, I found another possibility.  See my edit.  Also, in your particular script, you probably need to put a semicolon in there to break up the commands: `sudo bash ulimit -n 1000000; su - hadoop` or `sudo bash ulimit -n 1000000; ssh localhost`.